# problems using imports statements with Amazon SDK and Alamofire

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, cocoapods

I have followed [this tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/setup.html) to get my Amazon SDK up and running. 
It creates another project file with .xcworkspace extension that I have to use to be able to access all my Amazon SDK.

later I have edited the Podfile to include Almofire:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target :'MyTarget’ do
    pod 'AWSCognito'
    pod 'AWSS3'
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.4'
end
```

and ran pod install.

Everything executes correctly but when I import Alamofire in my .xcworkspace project it doesnt work but it works in  my old project. The reverse is true about my AWSS3 import.

I am new to IOS development and have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: by doesnt work I mean the import statement cant find the module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know how but I seem to fix the problem.
I have restarted the Mac OSX and have Changed my Podfile to reverse the order of Alamofire and AWS pods like so:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target :'MyTarget’ do
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.4'
    pod 'AWSCognito'
    pod 'AWSS3'
end
```

I have opened Xcode and the error has vanished.
Very bizarre